# Is it not wrong that intuitionistic logic is hard to convey?

Tags: logic, soft-question, intuitionistic-logic

As someone who is now mostly working in constructive / intuitionistic logic ($\mathsf{IL}$) I am still wondering about the most concise way to spotlight the relevance to people who so far only know about classical logic.

Most importantly I think it helps to give a convincing example showcasing why double negations cannot in general be removed. Before being aware of $\mathsf{IL}$ I definitely removed all seemingly unnecessary negations in any sentence I heard, just to ease comprehension. For example I would have read the sentence

> It's not wrong to say that I regularly removed too many negations.

as

> I regularly removed too many negations.

without suspecting that this could change the meaning. (After reading a bit it does also seem to depend on the language you speak, whether double negations cancel or not.)

My first questions are therefore:

1. Do you have a go-to example to illustrate why adapting $\mathsf{IL}$ is useful, even in *"every day"* logical endeavors?
2. Are there any *"natural language"* sentences using a double negation which would have a different meaning when we remove just them?

---

A related second issue is about the reading of double negations.
It is accurate but still a bit cumbersome to read $\neg \neg$ as "it is not wrong that ...".
Taking the following example as a benchmark:
$\neg \neg A \to \neg \neg (A \to B) \to \neg \neg B$ we get

> If it is not wrong to assume $A$ and it is not wrong that $A$ implies $B$, then it is not wrong to conclude $B$.

I have seen [one author](https://www.jstor.org/stable/2274603?seq=2#metadata_info_tab_contents) use the word *almost* to refer to $\neg \neg$ and I think this eases readability a bit:

> If we almost have $A$ and we almost have that $A$ implies $B$, then we almost have $B$.

But I imagine their being even better fits, which prompts my third question:

3. What is a pleasant and accurate word to read $\neg\neg$ by?

Comment: I think the [Kripke semantics for intuitionistic logic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kripke_semantics) is probably a good guide here. It suggests taking $\lnot\lnot A$ to mean that $A$ is consistent with our current and all future states of knowledge.

Comment: For some examples, you can also have a look at [inquisitive semantics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inquisitive_semantics): this is a system which extends intuitionistic logic: double negation can be removed for statementes, but not for arbitrary statements, such as questions.